# Why can't I run my node.js express web application

Tags: node.js, express

Node.js and the express generator are really handy and simple to understand. I cannot however get my server to start by running c:\my-application-root>DEBUG=my-application ./bin/www

Windows doesn’t seem to understand that command. I can however run it by calling node ./bin/www

Am i missing something?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you try `set DEBUG=my-application` followed by `node ./bin/www`? Windows does not allow setting an environment variable in the way that Linux and others do.

Comment: ah, yes. that is the reason. I knew it was more an OS thing and not an application issue

Answer (score 5):

1st command 'set DEBUG=my-application'.2nd command 'npm start'

Comment: what does npm start do here?

Comment: this run the npm provided package

Answer (score 2):

First you need to go the cmd that is supported by node (search for node cmd when you click in windows icon if you're using windows 7)
type 
set DEBUG=my-application
Second
simply cd c:\my-application\bin\ 
Then type
node www

www is the file that contains the script needed by node to run your server, DEBUG if set as an environment variable will also help you run node against it since the path will be known