# Why can't I run express.js application?

Tags: node.js, express

"DEBUG=my-application ./bin/www" this command work on mac os. why not working for windows 8.
is there any similar command?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I run my node.js express web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727413/why-cant-i-run-my-node-js-express-web-application)

Comment: yes " 'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Answer (score 1):

From the related question: [Why can't I run my node.js express web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727413/why-cant-i-run-my-node-js-express-web-application).

You cannot set environment variables in Windows in the same manner that you can on unix based systems (Linux, OS X etc.). This is why you are encountering the error: `DEBUG is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.