# Debug is not a recognized command (express)

Tags: node.js, express, windows-8.1

Im running express on windows 8. I ran the  command

```
>express app
```

after i ran the command to install dependencies

```
>cd app && npm install
```

after i attempted to run the app using the given command

```
>DEBUG=my-application ./bin/www
```

but I received the error message

```
'Debug' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

any ideas on how to fix this? 
Some background info, I successfully installed node.js from their website. I attempted to install express usings the commands

```
>npm install
```

when that didnt work i followed the instuctions on this website https://coderwall.com/p/mbov6w. when that didnt work i used the following command and it worked

```
npm install -g express-generator@3
```

i also made my own package.json and app.js based off the express website and i am now stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I run my node.js express web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727413/why-cant-i-run-my-node-js-express-web-application)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you must set DEBUG as a environment variable:

```
set DEBUG=my-application
```

then, you can run the app:

```
node bin/www
```

Answer (score 14):

For Windows : change your start command in the package.json file to

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set DEBUG=my-application & node ./bin/www"   
}
```

then you can run npm start.
There's no need to set the DEBUG environment variable in your cmd window first.

Answer (score 7):

In your root folder of your project you have to run this command

For Windows:

```
set DEBUG=express:* & node bin/www
```

Answer (score 4):

For windows environments you need to use `SET VARIABLE` for example

```
"scripts" : {
   "start" : "SET DEBUG=app & node ./bin/www"
}
```

That will help you with windows env but if you want to use cross platform I recommend to install this library [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) that library will help you to set variables for windows and linux environments.
And the json should look like this:

```
"scripts" : {
    "start" : "cross-env DEBUG=app & node ./bin/www"
}
```

I was having same issue and this help me!

Answer (score 4):

use this settings on your package.json

For window Users..

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "set DEBUG=app & node app.js"
  },
```

For Mac Users

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "DEBUG=app node app.js"
  },
```

**app** is your-app-name such as [app.js][server.js] etc.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the following steps for windows:

1. Go to your application i.e. cd app
2. npm install
3. set DEBUG=app
4. npm start

It will start listening on port 3000 by default.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue :

```
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command is for the windows users running on Git Bash with nodemon.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node index.js",
"dev": "SET DEBUG=app:* & nodemon index.js"
}
```