# Node.js DEBUG=appname nodemon not working on windows

Tags: node.js, express

Am following the tutorial by Mosh in Node.js and I  am not able to make this line of code work.

```
    DEBUG=app:db nodemon index.js
```

I got an error which is:

```
    'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
     operable program or batch file.`
```

While in his end it is working  fine.
[image]

Is this only works on MAC? I've also tried

```
    set DEBUG=app:db nodemon index.js
```

But still get the same error.

Well, I've seen and tried these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262196/debug-is-not-a-recognized-command-express/27472836) but still didn't work for me.

Could someone explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using windows, you must separate commands with `&&` separator:

`"scriptCommand": "set DEBUG=app:db&& nodemon index.js"`

Please note the there is NO space between `db` and `&&`. This is intentional, as the variable space spreads all the way to the && wall - meaning it will add an unintentional space after db to your variable.

Also, you perhaps would like to try the very useful and self-explanatory [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) library which allows you to use 1 syntax to declare an environment variable in any env (Win, Mac, Linux) the project is initialized in

Answer (score 1):

Try this "set DEBUG=app:* & nodemon index.js" on Windows. Then refresh your browser you will see the connection to the database.